# How Do I Make the Footer Stay at the Bottom of Every Page without Many Classes?

Tags: css, sass

I want to make the footer stay at the bottom of every page without making so many classes.

What I need is a footer that stays at the bottom of every page, no matter if the content is too scarce, without being "sticky," or using position: fixed.

I've done my research and looked at other answers on other questions but they've either got so many classes, they use position: fixed, or they use JS.

Here's the code for the layout.pug file:

```html
.footer-wrapper
    footer &copy; 2018 Demo Website
```

And the code that I tried in SCSS is here:

```css
.footer-wrapper {
    // min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
    background-color: #0A0A0A;
    color: white;
    // height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    // display: grid;
    // margin-top: auto;
    // padding:10px;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Let flex-grow property handle the height of the `.content` container.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>

<style>
    .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .content{ flex-grow: 1; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, @anderssonola! This worked for me on the home page. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a really cheap way of doing this, which is actually quite good.

Assuming you're using a header as well, you could do something like this:

```
<header>
<div id = "body">
<footer>
...
<style scoped = "scss">
#body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    margin-top: <header_height>;
    margin-bottom: <footer_height>;
}
</style>
```

Basically it sets the body content to fill up the entire page, but leaves room for the header at the top of the page, and room for the footer at the bottom of the page (if there is no flexing). When there is not enough room to fit the body content on the page, the body div will flex in the column, automatically moving the footer with it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Daynarc! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This worked for me as well, though I'm using @anderssonola's answer. Thank you! :)